# What are Kant's critiques of Hume's and Descartes's conceptions of the self?

Tags: kant, philosophy-of-mind, descartes, hume, self

What are Kant's critiques of Descartes's conception of the self contained in the *Metaphysical Meditations* and of Hume's conception of the self expressed in the *Essay concerning human understanding*? Why does he accept neither that the self is ensured by the the continuity of the thinking substance, as Descartes said, nor that it is due to the continuity of the mind, as Hume tried unsuccessfuly to prove?